# Get pic names from folders with PHP - then look for numbers in them, then insert into MySQL table for each number respectively

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

I have this folder `d:/data/pics`, with pics called `1101-a.jpg`, `1101-b.jpg`, `1102-a.jpg`, `1102-b.jpg` etc. Pics a and b of the same number always - note that this a and b are merely representation of the text after the 'number-' part. but for each number there are 2 results always.

And I have a MySQL database with table 'pics'. It has columns 'id', 'number', 'title1' and 'title2'. The 'number' column has the 1101, 1102, 1103 etc. already.

I need to lookup all the pics from the directory, get the numbers out from their names, look up the same numbers in my MySQL table and insert the appropriate pics names into the database. For each number there are two pics.

Now, I know how to get the names from directory, but I fail in inserting it in the database, because I have two pics of the same number that I need to pair up with same row in my mySQL afterwards.

```
     $directory = opendir("d:/data/images"); 
     $image_format = array("jpg, jpeg, png");
     $image_names = array(); 
     while ($file = readdir ($directory)) {
     if(in_array(substr(strtolower($file), strrpos($file,".") + 1),$image_format))
     {
     array_push($image_names,$file);
      }
     foreach ($image_names as $row) {
     //HERE I NEED THE NUMBER IN PIC'S NAME EXTRACTED AS A VALUE FOR EACH PIC:
     $pic_number = "$_GET INTEGER FROM IMAGE_NAMES (or $row)" ;
     // this i don't know.
     $id = $_GET($row['id']);
     $number = $_GET($row['number']);
     //NOW HERE I NEED THAT $pic_number FROM image_names ABOVE... and then
     $sql = "INSERT INTO images (title1, title2) VALUES ($row) WHERE $number = $pic_number;";
     mysql_query($sql); 
     }
     }
     closedir($directory);
```

I wrote short without escape to simplify the problem as much as I could.

Comment: Your insert looks kind of odd. You are listing two columns in your column list (`title1` and `title2`), but only one value `$row`. Plus, you have a `where` clause. Mysql (and most databases) don't support a `where` clause in an insert. `where` is for `select`, `update` and `delete` where as `insert` is for adding new rows, not referencing existing ones.

Comment: i agree it's odd :) ... and that i should use UPDATE seems logical. thanx i'll try something with it.

Comment: So let me check something, all you need to do is update the `images` table, set `title1` to the first image name found and `title2` to the second where the number exists in the database? no other columns need modifying right? What about images that don't have a number in the database or vice versa with rows that don't have an image?

Comment: Also, roughly how many images/rows? This could likely be reduced down to a single call to [glob](http://www.php.net/glob), loop over and process that array and then a single update query with a `IN (LIST)` that would do everything at once.

Comment: there are NO images that don't have a number. all of them have a number that's already in the dbase table 'pics', column 'number'.

Comment: If it's not always 'a' na 'b' (as you wrote in comment below) then it doesn't matter which filename goes into name1 column and which name2. Right? (btw. Do you want stored names to contain extracted number?)

Comment: The first result (of the two) for given number goes in title1, the second should go to title2. Stored names of the pics should go as found in the folder (1101-something.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
$images = glob("d:/data/images/*-a.{jpg,png,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE));
foreach($images as $img){
$path_parts = pathinfo($img);
$img = $path_parts['basename'];
$ext = $path_parts['extension'];

$imge = explode('-',$img);
$pic_number = $imge[0];

$file1 = $pic_number."-a.".$ext;
$file2 = $pic_number."-b.".$ext;

.....
}
```

Comment: use [`basename`](http://www.php.net/basename) to get the filename instead of string_replace.

Comment: also if we assume all images have an A and B counterpart then just index the number column as unique ans do an INSERT IGNORE querry

Comment: depends on whether OP is trying to actually do an insert or update existing records. That's all my comment was about as it appeared OP was trying to insert values to an existing record which is really an update.

Comment: Update, update - my mistake was with insert... now i got some of it to work.  some of it... the echo $img (as @Max D called it) gives me listing, all good. echo $pic_number gives me the number all good.

i connected it with the the dbase.
but the $img has 2 values. A and B (some text and another text) after the number... i need img1 and img2 for updating values into title1 and title2...  any ideas for that?
What would it look like 
SQL = update pics (title1, title2) VALUES (img1, img2) where number = $pic_number ? right?

Comment: see my edits above... if we only glob files with -a then just create a string with expected 2 file names

Comment: unfortunately it's not always A or B, sometims it's a text (name) ... can't use -a or -b in line... can it be $pic_number."*.*".$ext ?

Comment: File-exists doesn't help me much :( 
File (image name) EXISTS always. We got the pic_number that's important. now it is valid for an array of 2 values/pic names. 

how to separate those two values into rows? for each $pic_number as part1 and part2... that is my problem one id number 2 values for it :( i need both extracted as part1 and part2 so i can update dbase with it

Answer (score 0):

Two loops solution is the way to go imo. Efficient multi-row update is possible if you set **unique index on `number` column** (which you should anyway). You could utilize MySQL `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause then. Before use the code below be sure to have unique index on `number` column (unique `id` is not enough):

```
$img_files = glob("files/*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG,jpeg,JPEG}", GLOB_BRACE);
$data = array();
foreach ($img_files as $img_file) {
    $filename = basename($img_file);
    $split_filename = explode('-', $filename, 2);
    $number_prefix = (int) $split_filename[0];
    $data[$number_prefix][] = $filename;
}

// assuming 0 can't be prefix number $data[0] represents invalid file (without number prefix) - not needed aparently
// unset($data[0]);

$insert_values = '';
foreach ($data as $number => $row) {
    $title1 = $row[0];
    $title2 = isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : ''; // empty string in case there's no second file
    $insert_values .= "('$number','$title1','$title2'),";
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO images (number, title1, title2) VALUES ' . substr($insert_values, 0, -1) . '
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title1 = VALUE(title1), title2 = VALUE(title2)';
//... run query
```

without index `UPDATE` queries are easy to build within second loop (have number and both filenames).

Edit: Looped `UPDATE` version:

```
//... $insert_values not needed
foreach ($data as $number => $row) {
    $title1 = $row[0];
    $title2 = isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : ''; // empty string in case there's no second file
    $sql = "UPDATE images SET title1 = '$title1', title2 = '$title2' WHERE number = $number";
    // ... execute query
}
```

Comment: Again this works partially. (I had to remove [0] in upper synthax and values .= in lower. but after that it worked partially - the $insert _values echo nicely, all of them ($number, $title1, $title2) but sql should be UPDATE not insert. 
something like 
sql = update images SET number=$number, title1=$title1, title2=$title2 WHERE number=$number... but it's not working ... although i do think this is the way to go ; here it's just the issue of proper synthax

Comment: As I wrote. You may do it with `UPDATE` query inside loop. This is special `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` trick that allows multiple updates in single query (`.=` part is not an error). I'll write you `UPDATE` scenario underneath in a moment.

Comment: unfortunately, with this one i get false $number result (instead of 1101 , for a file 1101-sometext.jpg and 1101-someothertext.jpg) i get 1 for as many of images i have it displays array of ones...
so update won't work :(

Comment: That `[0]` you had to remove was in `$number_prefix` line? I forgot it might not work for older php versions - I've edited code. Btw. I might have misunderstood your previous comment, so if `0` can't be number prefix afterall uncomment that `unset()` part.

Comment: No, this time the $number is ok ; but update isn't working again again :(  i keep getting syntax error near title2 = $title2 part... maybe its' something relate to my perhaps older version od server/php/mysql?

Comment: Ahh forgot about quotes  - got used to PDO's parametrized queries (which I recommend). Query updated.